# Can't get Server 2012 Evaluation download to install

Tags: windows-server-2012, installation, evaluation

I have downloaded both server standard and essentials and put the Iso onto a USB stick and tried to install them on a virgin server with clean drives which are formatted.

The USB boots and starts the install and then comes up looking a license key?
Checked emails, check in the USB image no key.

Maybe I am missing the elephant here but have had to pull the intended OS drive and plug linux back in.

Tech pages absolutely no help at all?

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation versions of Windows Server require the server to be connected to the internet to activate. Alternatively you can phone or grab a 10 days grace period.

> Steps to Activate Software License
>
> Connect to the internet, which will allow the software licensing service >to attempt activation
> Telephone activation
> Users with no internet connectivity can trigger the 10-day grace period by running the following commands from an elevated command prompt:
>
> Slmgr /rearm
>
> Shutdown –r

Comment: The server is on the internet and as it installs stops looking key?

Comment: Can you ping the server? I'd recommend activating the 10 day grace period and take it from there. I had the same issue recently. The server wouldn't connect to the internet until I booted into Windows and installed the correct drivers.

Comment: The problem is with the HP server, got into the advance Config and told it to install from the USB , no probs.

Comment: So you were trying to install with Intelligent Provisioning?